# Slow results when using webkitSpeechRecognition vs x-webkit-speech?

Tags: webkit, speech-recognition

I'm new to using this API and wasnt able to find an answer to what I'm running into.

When I use `new webkitSpeechRecognition`, and use the `onresult` event to find `isFinal == true`, it seems to take longer in finding the final result than using `x-webkit-speech` in an input tag.

Does anyone know if google is doing something specific to get a speedier result?  Or do I need to set an attribute in the webkitSpeechRecognition object?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414548/1363) which explains how, in continuous mode results are triggered by new voice input, or otherwise will show up only after a timeout.
In non continuous mode, the result will show up much faster.