# webkitSpeechRecognition is "lagging" behind when gathering results

Tags: javascript, api, webkit, speech-to-text, webspeech-api

Had an itch to try out the [Web Speech API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API).
I copied the code exactly from the article, and I'm having an issue where you speak, but nothing happens until you speak AGAIN.

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w75v2tm5/]

JS:

```
if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
    //handle error stuff here...
} else {
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = false;

    recognition.start();

    var final_transcript = '';

    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        var interim_transcript = '';
        if (typeof (event.results) == 'undefined') {
            recognition.onend = null;
            recognition.stop();
            upgrade();
            return;
        }
        for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
            if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                final_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            } else {
                interim_transcript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerText = final_transcript;
    };

}
```

For example, if I were to say "Hello world", the <div> I have set up to display the results would not display "Hello world" until I said something else, or made a sound. But if I said something else, THAT would not be displayed until I said something else AGAIN.

The variable "final_transcript" is holding the PREVIOUS result, and not what I just said. It's off by just 1.

To give you a better idea...

Me: "Hello world"

final_transcript = '';

[Wait...]

Me: "Test"

final_transcript = 'Hello world'

And this just continues. The code is failing to transcribe what I am saying AS I am saying it. Very weird.

Any thoughts as to why this could be?

Answer (score 8):

There is some kind of built in timeout, after which you will get the result even if there is no more input (seems to be around 5-10 seconds).

In this case you will get the final `onresult` event, as well as the `onend` event. You will have to call `recognition.start()` again if you wish to keep accepting input.

Also, if you set

```
recognition.interimResults = true;
```

you will get `onresult` events with non final results, and you can decide if you want to display them before you get the final ones.

The other option is to turn off continuous with

```
recognition.continuous = false;
```

you will get a result shortly after the input (audio) stopped.
You will also get the `onend` event.
If you wish to continue the recognition you will have to call again

```
recognition.start();
```

in the `onend` event handler.
**On a non HTTPS page, this will cause the permission bar to pop up again.**

see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/w75v2tm5/1/)

Comment: I have the same experience as Ron Harlev: non-lagging results are best achieved by setting recognition.continuous = false and restarting the recognition when the onend event occurs.